# Eclipse Maven Update cleans jaxb generated classes and Regenerates them without taking the class name tag into account

Tags: eclipse, maven, jaxb

I have troubles with eclipse / maven in Netbeans it's working as expected.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jxb:bindings xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
               xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"
               jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc"
               version="2.1">

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="http://myserver/schemas/CustomerOrder_v1.7.xsd" node="/xsd:schema">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xsd:element[@name='customerOrder']">
            <jxb:class name="ElectronicCustomerOrder"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
        <jxb:bindings node="//xsd:element[@name='deliveryDate']" multiple="true">
            <xjc:javaType adapter="com.prodega.xml.JodaTimeDateAdapter" name="org.joda.time.LocalDate" />
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>

</jxb:bindings>
```

if i do a maven update in eclipse (photon or mars) it generates a class called CustomerOrder into the target:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCk7T.png)

But i'm expecting a class named `ElectronicCustomerOrder`. As soon i make a change in the xjb file and save it, it renames the class in the target folder. But then the building workspace part is done and it didn't find the class `ElectronicCustomerOrder`. Can someone Tell me what's happening here since it's anoying to build on commandline and then do a refresh in eclipse.

A normal `mvn clean install` command will work also properly.